# Plot confidence interval for AUC for two models in R

Tags: r, plot, roc

I have plotted the ROC curve of two models and I would like to have the AUC confidence internal as a band. Any idea?
The code I use is:

```
library(pRoc)
roc(test_df$extry, y, plot=TRUE, legacy.axes=TRUE, percent=TRUE, xlab="False Positive Percentage", ylab="True Postive Percentage", col="#377eb8", lwd=4,print.auc=TRUE)
plot.roc(test_df$extry, rf.model$votes[,1], percent=TRUE, col="#4daf4a", lwd=4, print.auc=TRUE, add=TRUE, print.auc.y=40)
```

Comment: The confidence interval for an AUC _isn't_ a band. The AUC is a single number pertaining to the whole curve and therefore its confidence interval applies to the whole curve. You can't define it at each value on the x axis to generate a band.

Comment: Can you show us what you have already? It would help if you could make a reproducible example as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/333599 ...